# Restrict access to web site by its IP address

Tags: apache-httpd

When I go to my site `www.mysite.com` by port 80/tcp, it redirects me to https 443/tcp. It is ok. 
But when I go to link `https://xx.xx.xx.xx` (by its ip address), I can easily access it 
and it gives me not trusted site.

I want to restrict any access to my web site by its IP address. 
My web server is apache 
. I tried adding these lines of codes to 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xx.xx.xx.xx (ip address)
Redirect 403 /
ErrorDocument 403 “Sorry, direct IP access not allowed.”
DocumentRoot /dev/null/
UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

It gives me error when restarting apache.
At the moment I have this configuration in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
Redirect / https://www.mysite.com/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: `/dev/null/` does not exist - note the trailing slash. Did you mean `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
Redirect / https://www.mysite.com/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

because it redirects *everything*. You need to put your 403 deny in there. Then copy the Redirect into your `001-yoursite.conf` with an appropriate ServerName. Then http://yoursite will be redirected to https://yoursite, but http://IPADDRESS will bounce because it will hit the default. So will http://anyothersite, as it should be.

Then you *also* need to add a default server as SSL (I imagine it would be 000-default-ssl.conf) with the same denial for `*:443`, so that https://whatever will bounce unless "whatever" matches your servername, thereby landing in `001-yoursite-ssl.conf`.

**You needn't specify DocumentRoot** if all you're doing is issuing a `403 Forbidden`. And you probably don't need to bother with error log and access log, it will be just bot traffic anyway (you can define a very minimal access_log format if you really need it - just source IP and maybe user-agent for bot classification).

Comment: Can I add the configurations that you said to my existing configuration somehow? Assuming that I won't create new 000-default-ssl.conf files.

Comment: I tried to create new 001-mysite-ssl.conf and do as the same way. Still does not work. Should I use a2ensite 001-mysite-ssl.conf command after creating it?

Comment: in Ubuntu, you prepare your conf files in `/etc/apache/sites-available` and then enable them with `a2ensite`.